# Hybrid Graphics cannot switch, ATI drivers can't find adapter?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, vgaswitcheroo

It all started when I tried to install Steam to play some Left 4 Dead 2. I noticed it probably wasn't using my discrete graphics card (AMD 7670m) and was using my integrated card, as it was lagging pretty badly. I tried using vgaswitcheroo to switch the card, but it simply would not switch to the discrete card. Finally, I tried installing some brand new AMD drivers from AMD's website. When I do

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

...nothing happens. The output is

```
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

A similar error occurs when using amdconfig (not sure what the difference is...). Can anyone offer any help?

EDIT: Forgot to mention: xorg.conf also seems to be missing from its usual place (etc/X11/xorg.conf)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, try edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `radeon.runpm=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` so something similar to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.runpm=1"
```

save and run `sudo update-grub` then reboot.

Also try `sudo aticonfig --initial --px-dgpu` if `--adapter=all` isn't working.